# unable to load from csv to mysql in java?

Tags: mysql, csv

```
   String query =LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'airline.csv' INTO TABLE airline_tweets1  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' (tweet_id BIGINT,airline_sentiment VARCHAR,airline_sentiment_confidence DOUBLE,negativereason VARCHAR,negativereason_confidence VARCHAR,airline VARCHAR,airline_sentiment_gold VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,negativereason_gold VARCHAR,retweet_count INT,text VARCHAR,tweet_coord VARCHAR,tweet_created VARCHAR,tweet_location VARCHAR,user_timezone VARCHAR);

     stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

when i run the above query i get

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'BIGINT,airline_sentiment VARCHAR,airline_sentiment_confidence
>   DOUBLE,negativerea' at line 1

How can i solve this?

Comment: You don't put the datatypes in the query. They're just used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement that creates the table in the first place.

Comment: The sytax must be:

[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}

not [{FIELDS |TYPE} see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't list the datatypes of the columns in the `LOAD DATA` query. They're just used when creating the table with a `CREATE TABLE` query.

```
   String query =LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'airline.csv' INTO TABLE airline_tweets1  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' (tweet_id, airline_sentiment, airline_sentiment_confidence, negativereason, negativereason_confidence, airline , airline_sentiment_gold, name, negativereason_gold, retweet_count, text, tweet_coord, tweet_created, tweet_location, user_timezone);
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE hr_analytics([NO] INT,[SATISFACTION_LEVEL] DOUBLE,[LAST_EVALUATION] DOUBLE,[NUMBER_PROJECT] INT,[AVERAGE_MONTLY_HOURS] INT,[TIME_SPEND_COMPANY] INT,[WORK_ACCIDENT] INT,[LEFT] INT,[PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS] INT,[SALES] VARCHAR(200),[SALARY] VARCHAR(200))` isnt this query right? i am getting exception :                                                           You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[NO] INT,[SATISFACTION_LEVEL] DOUBLE,[LAST_EVALUATION] DOUBLE,[NUMBER_PROJECT] I' at line 1

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `[]` around names, it uses backticks. You're confusing it with SQL-Server.